# Should Binary Heap be a binary tree or linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, linked-list

I have an assignment to implement a binary heap. However, I'm not sure whether I should implement the binary heap as a binary tree data structure or a simple double linked list.

If I should implement as a binary tree, how should I keep track of the last element of the tree in order to insert a new element? In linked list that would be much easier.

So, does binary heap have to be a binary tree? If yes, how to track the last element?

Note: In my assignment there is a statement like this:
**But you will implement the binary heap not as an array, but
as a tree.**

To be more clear this is my node:

```
struct Word{
    char * word;
    int count;
    struct Word * parent;
    struct Word * left_child;
    struct Word * right_child;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution taken from the question.
by @Yunus Eren Güzel
**SOLVED:**

After five hours of study I have found a way to implement heap as a pointer based tree.
The insertion algorithm is :

```
insert
    node = create_a_node
    parent = get_the_last_parent
    node->parent = parent
    if parent->left==NULL
        parent->left=node
    else
        parent->right=node
end insert

get_last_parent parent,&height
    height++
    if parent->left==NULL || parent->right==NULL
        return parent;
    else
        int left_height=0,right_height=0;
        left = get_last_parent(parent->left,&left_height)
        right = get_last_parent(parent->right,&right_height)
        if left_height == right_height
            height += right_height
            return right
        else if left_height > right_height
            height += left_height
            return left
end get_last_parent
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

A binary heap is, by definition, a binary tree.  One way of implementing this in C is to store the tree elements in an array where the array index corresponds to the tree element (numbering the root node 0, its left child 1, its right child 2, and so on). You can then just store the size of the heap (initialized to 0 upon creation and incremented whenever an element is added) and use that to find the next open location.

For basic data structures questions like this, [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

Comment: thanks, but the assignment has that statement:
"But you will implement the binary heap not as an array, but
as a tree."

Answer (score 0):

You should implement it as a tree. It will be easy and interesting. Heap has only property that any node has value less than or equal to its parent, if it is a max heap.
In array implementation we impose some more conditions.
If you need help about specific function implementation then you can ask it.

You need to travel down to add new node

call it with root, value to be inserted

```
    insert(node, x){

    if(node->value >= x)
      //insert
      if(node->left == 0)
          node->left = new Node(x);
      else if(node->right == 0)
          node->right = new Node(x);
      else if(node->left->value >= x)
         insert(node->left, x);
      else if(node->right->value >= x)
         insert(node->right, x);
      else
         //insert between node and its any one child
         insertBW(node, node->left, x);
   else  //if x is less than node value
      //insert between node and its parent
      insertBW(node->parent, node, x)
   }
```

insertBW(p, c) is a function which insets a node containing value x between p and c

(I didn't tested this code please check for errors)

```
insertBW(Node* p, Node* c, T x)
{
    Node* newnode = new Node(x);
    newNode.x = x;
    if(p == 0)  //if node c is root
    {
       newnode.left = Tree.root.left;
       Tree.root = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
       newnode.parent = p;
       newnode.child  = c;
       if(p.left == c)
       {
           p.left = newnode;
       }
       else p.right = newnode;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you tell me how to keep track of the last element that i will use when i insert a new node, it would be useful for me if you give that as an algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your afford, but I have questions in my mind. Does insertBW makes a heapify call? If not, it ruins the data structure. Can you give me the insertBW algorithm?

Comment: I see that you did not think keeping heap structure as a complate binary tree. Your solution is not for a heap, but for a free form binary tree.

Comment: the condition >= makes it heap

Answer (score 0):

This to me really seems to be a homework question & it seems you have not done any R&D on your own before asking (sorry for bit harsh words):)

In computer science, a heap is a specialized tree-based data structure that satisfies the heap property:  if B is a child node of A, then key(A) ≥ key(B).

I think your teacher wants you to implement a priority queue data structure and that's where you are talking about both a Linked List and Heap together in the same question. Priority Queue can be implemented as a Heap or a Linked List where in to extract elements based on priority either you have to maintain elements sorted in case of linked list where say a maximum or minimum element goes at the front based upon whether you are implementing a max heap or a min heap OR priority queue can be implemented simply as a heap data structure.

Coming to the last point where you say "But you will implement the binary heap not as an array, but as a tree.", seems to be very irrelevant. Please do check again as to what is required or reproduce the exact question that has been asked in your assignment.

Comment: I have researched Binary Heap implementation as a binary heap structure but I could not find any helpful resource. I think the question is clear, tell me what you don't understand and I revise it.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, regarding your first question - no. A heap can be anything (array, linked list, tree, and when one must improvise a family of fluffy kittens). Note the definition of a heap: If "B" is a child of "A" then val(A) >= val(B) (or, in case of a min-heap, val(A) <= val(B)).
It's most common to refer to it as a tree (and also implement it as such) because it's easy to think of it as a tree. Also, the time-complexity & performance are good.

Regarding your second question, you gave no information, so as far as I know a solution that searches every node is as good as any other...
For any better answer, more information is required (what limitations do you have, what operations should you support, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

A binary heap can be anything i.e. array, linked list, tree, etc. We just have to keep the right algorithm on how can you can access the data. For example, if you want to make it to the left child you can do this by 2*N + 1(For starting index 0) where N is the parent index or the right child by 2*N + 2. For the last element, you can initialise the heap with a variable count and increment it by 1 every time you insert a new element, this way you can keep track of the last element (Same for delete, just some modification has to be made on the collection).